# Php number out of text?

Tags: php, string

Im new here. I need help with php.

```
$FullDescriptionLine = Model 23MP48HQ-P|23"|Panel IPS|Resolution 1920x1080|Form factor 16:9|
```

how can i get `23"` out of that string?

Thank you
Martin

Comment: Try `explode('|', $FullDescriptionLine)[1]`

Comment: [Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e284b60d962ef016b8b2231eb3e02c89cf85173b)

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string on pipes (`|`), then get the second index (`1` in computer indexes) of that array.

```
$FullDescriptionLine = 'Model 23MP48HQ-P|23"|Panel IPS|Resolution 1920x1080|Form factor 16:9|';
echo explode('|', $FullDescriptionLine)[1];
```

[Online PHP demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fbeeaee0689913baae758aeba972428be19ab095)

Comment: I obviously need to stop and clean my spectacles :) Or go and have a coffee.

Answer (score 3):

Just `explode()` it with pipe `|` character and grab the first i.e `1st` **index** as array starts from `0` index.

```
<?php
  $FullDescriptionLine = 'Model 23MP48HQ-P|23"|Panel IPS|Resolution 1920x1080|Form factor 16:9|';
  $array = explode('|',$FullDescriptionLine);
  //just for debug and clearly understand it
  print '<pre>';
  print_r($array);
  print '</pre>';
  echo $array[1];
 ?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/8aGuO

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. It converts a given string into array elements, separated by a delimiter. It takes two inputs, a delimiter string (`'|'`) and the string to convert into array chunks (`$FullDescriptionLine`).

Now, in your case, `23"` is in the second substring (array index `1` - remember that array indexing start from 0). Post exploding the string, you can get the value using index `[1]`.

Try the following (**[Rextester DEMO](http://rextester.com/LOKO23881)**):

```
$FullDescriptionLine = 'Model 23MP48HQ-P|23"|Panel IPS|Resolution 1920x1080|Form factor 16:9|';

// explode the string and access the value
$result = explode('|', $FullDescriptionLine)[1];
echo $result;  // displays 23"
```

Answer (score 1):

For structured strings I recommend `str_getcsv` and then use the second parameter to define the delimiter.

```
$array = str_getcsv('Model 23MP48HQ-P|23"|Panel IPS|Resolution 1920x1080|Form factor 16:9|', '|');
echo $array[1];
```

https://3v4l.org/7XSDQ

Comment: @Mohammad Although, IMHO, `str_getcsv` is better suited, since `str_getcsv` is specifically built for parsing CSVs, which this string seems to be.

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, but if you were to have these values encapsulated it will be much easier to use this function than explode.

Answer (score 0):

Using `explode()` is simple and good that multiple user posted it. But there is another way. Using regex in `preg_match()`

```
preg_match("/\|([^|]+)/", $FullDescriptionLine, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/D7q3r)

Comment: Using regex for this is overkill. That's like cutting a slice of bread with a chainsaw while having a bread knife next to you. (In my opinion)